# My Clojure code doesn't produce any output on HackerRank, but it does everywhere else

Tags: clojure, jvm

Currently I'm solving this problem
"https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fp-sum-of-odd-elements"

Here's my code

```
(fn func[lst]
  ((fn sumOdd[sum, index]
   (if (< index (.size lst))
     (do
      (if (= (mod (get lst index) 2) 1)
        (do
          (sumOdd (+ sum (get lst index)) (+ index 1))
          )
        (do
          (sumOdd (+ sum 0) (+ index 1))
          )
      )
     )
    sum
   )
 )0 0)
)
```

In HackerRank, it supposes to call the anonymous function with list as an input parameter, however, my code produces nothing at all but it does locally on my machine. I tried the following code on HackerRank:

```
(fn [lst] lst)
```

and the does produce the output as `lst`. What am I doing wrong here that made my code not universally the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a bug so far in your solution.

The problem statement does not guarantee that the first parameter of solution functions properly responds to the `get` function.

- If it is given as a list, applying the `get` function against it returns `nil`.
- e.g. `(get '(1 2 3) 1) ;=> nil`

Comment: Oh, thanks !! it really is the problem with "(get '(1 2 3) 1)" I didn't realize I used vector instead of list

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(fn [lst] (reduce + (filter odd? lst)))
```